# terraform loop external input

Tags: bash, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

import databases via data source dynamically(created separately via ansible).

command output is form of list which should be accepted for terraform for_each

```
data "azurerm_sql_server" "sql_server" {
  name         = "sql-server-mon-test"
  resource_group_name = "ex-net-rg" 
}

data "external" "databases_ids" {
  program = ["sh", "${path.module}/db_id.sh"]
  query = {
    db_rg   = data.azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.resource_group_name
    server_name      = data.azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.name
  }
}

data "azurerm_sql_database" "database" {
  for_each            = toset(data.external.databases_ids.result["name_of_db"])
  name                = each.key
  server_name         = data.azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.resource_group_name
}
```

Bash code:

```
eval "$(jq -r '@sh "export DB_RG=\(.db_rg) SERVER_NAME=\(.server_name)"')"

if [[ -z $DB_RG || -z $SERVER_NAME ]]; then
echo "Required variables DB_RG & SERVER_NAME not set" 1>&2
exit 1
fi

name_of_db=$(az sql db list --resource-group $DB_RG --server $SERVER_NAME --query [*].name 2>/dev/null)

jq -n --arg name_of_db"$name_of_db" '{"name_of_db":$name_of_db}'

unset DB_RG SERVER_NAME name_of_db

exit 0
```

ERROR :

```
 Error: Invalid function argument
 on main.tf line 37, in data "azurerm_sql_database" "database":
      37:   for_each            = toset(data.external.databases_ids.result["name_of_db"])
      data.external.databases_ids.result["name_of_db"] is "\"db1\""

Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert string to set of any single
type.*
```

Sample az command output :

```
az sql db list --resource-group ex-net-rg  --server sql-server-mon-test --query [*].name
[
  "db1",
  "db2",
  "master"
]
```

Edit 1: More debugging :
Bash script output :

```
    {
  "name_of_db": "[\n  \"db1\",\n  \"db2\",\n  \"master\"\n]"
}
```

added local block in terraform code to populate state file :

```
locals {
database_name =(jsondecode(data.external.databases_ids.result["name_of_db"]))
}
```

tfstate file generated :

```
"query": {
          "db_rg": "ex-net-rg",
          "server_name": "sql-server-mon-test"
        },
        "result": {
          "name_of_db": "[\n  \"db1\",\n  \"db2\",\n  \"master\"\n]"
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add probably `jsondecode` there:

```
for_each            = toset(jsondecode(data.external.databases_ids.result["name_of_db"]))
```